# how to get mediaplayer audioSession for Equalizer

Tags: android, kotlin, equalizer

I am implementing a custom equalizer that requires an audio session during initialization.
Equalizer(int priority, int audioSession)

There are some apps in the Google Play Store that can set their equalizer to Spotify or YT music. How can I get the current media player app's audio session to set it in the equalizer? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use 0 as audio session for global music in android.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).